# ntp.conf being rewritten in Fedora

Tags: dhcp, fedora, ntp

Something rewrites my `ntp.conf` on reboot. It's easy to google that DHCP client may do it, and there is a simple solution for that. Just including `-N` option into `dhcpcd_eth` in `/etc/conf.d/net` should be enough.

It's fine except on Fedora there is no `/etc/conf.d/net`. We have `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` and I have no idea how to apply given solution to them. Maybe I'm even looking for a wrong thing is a wrong place.

How to tell DHCP not to touch `ntp.conf` on Fedora?

Comment: I'd suggest just making the file immutable with `chattr`.

Comment: Which release of Fedora?

Comment: Fedora 12. Yes, I know.

Comment: On RHEL6 (ages newer in redhatish terms) the relevant code appears to be in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/ntp.sh